# How to install, configure and run supervisor in amazon linux ami?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, supervisord, amazon-linux

I am trying to install supervisor in amazon linux ami but couldnt do it.

I tried below:

```
sudo yum install supervisor - said no supervisor
```

then did

```
sudo easy_install supervisor
```

But I cannot find supervisor folder at /etc

Also, supervisorctl command is not there

Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the output I got when I run `sudo easy_install supervisor`

```
[ec2-user@ip address ~]$ sudo easy_install supervisor
Searching for supervisor
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/supervisor/
Best match: supervisor 3.3.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/31/7e/788fc6566211e77c395ea272058eb71299c65cc5e55b6214d479c6c2ec9a/supervisor-3.3.3.tar.gz#md5=0fe86dfec4e5c5d98324d24c4cf944bd
Processing supervisor-3.3.3.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-fl_Ycg/supervisor-3.3.3/setup.cfg
Running supervisor-3.3.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-fl_Ycg/supervisor-3.3.3/egg-dist-tmp-QhXQQZ
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/.build'
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.3.3-py2.7.egg
Extracting supervisor-3.3.3-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding supervisor 3.3.3 to easy-install.pth file
Installing echo_supervisord_conf script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pidproxy script to /usr/local/bin
Installing supervisorctl script to /usr/local/bin
Installing supervisord script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.3.3-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for supervisor
Finished processing dependencies for supervisor
```

Notice the lines:

```
Installing supervisorctl script to /usr/local/bin
Installing supervisord script to /usr/local/bin
```

So they can be found in `/usr/local/bin`, which should be in your `PATH`. You can check that with `echo $PATH`.

You can check the [official doc](http://supervisord.org/installing.html#creating-a-configuration-file) for more info.